# how to always start conemu in maximized mode?

Tags: conemu

I have checked the "auto save windows size and position on exit" and have the window maximized, but after I closes conemu and start it again it is not started as maximized. Any suggestions?

Comment: @downvoter, why downvote this question? Off topic, not a question or what is your reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Left click on the shortcut to conemu, select "Properties", go to the "Shortcut" tab, select the "Run:" dropdown, and choose "Maximized".

[image: screencap illustrating what to do]

Answer (score 0):

The command line parameter is `/Max`. You can create a batch file for that.